# access array member

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
for (int i=0; i<[data count]; i++) {
NSArray *item = [data objectAtIndex: i];
//NSString *index = item->id;
NSLog(@"%@", item);
}
```

This has an output of:

```
2011-03-07 20:48:46.949 hest[1796:207] {
    id = 1;
    src = "http://img0.gmodules.com/ig/images/igoogle_logo_sm.png";
}
```

But when doing:

```
NSString *index = item->id;
```

It fails with an output of:

```
struct NSArray has no member named id
```

What is the correct way to access members?

Comment: Sorry Dave, didn't know you were editing at the same time. :)

Comment: Just a hint: if you are using `->` in objective-C, 99% chance you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @amattn: I'd say more like 80% of the time; it's not uncommon to see struct references getting passed around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell from the formatting of the logged object that it's not actually an `NSArray`.  It's an `NSDictionary`.  If you're unfamiliar with the two, here's a basic idea: an array stores objects based on an integer position.  A dictionary stores things based on a "key".

To pull a value out of a dictionary, you use it's "objectForKey:" method:

```
id value = [item objectForKey:@"id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the item returned from `[data objectAtIndex: i]` to a local variable typed as an `NSArray`. You should use the actual type you expect the data array to contain.

```
NSArray *item = [data objectAtIndex: i];
```

should be something like

```
MyImageDataType *item = [data objectAtIndex: i];
```